# Express relationship between two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to write a formula to express a relationship between two variables $a$ and $b$.

If $a$ has value below $30$, $b$ should be zero.

If $a$ has value is between $30$ and $90$, $b$ should increase $a:b$ by $2:1$.

And if $a$ value is above $90$, $b$ should increase by $4:1$.

Is this possible to express as a formula?

Comment: You could express $b$ as a piecewise function of $a$.

Comment: A terse description like "should increase a:b by p:q" is ambiguous. Spend some time explaining what you want.

Comment: As a single formula? You would get something very complicated. But as three formulae, a simple linear function does it.

Comment: @Allawonder But you mean it is still possible to write as a single formula?

Comment: @LennyWhite Yes, of course. An infinite series of sines and cosines, for example.

Comment: @Allawonder Haha well I'll go for piecewise function then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $b(a)$ is a [*piecewise-defined function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) $b:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

And, from your comment here below my answer:

> By example when $a$ is $45$, $b$ should be $(45−30)/2=7.5$. When $a$ is $120$, $b$ should be $30+(120−60)/4=45$

substituting $a$, we should get:

$$
b(a)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if} & a<30\\[2px]
\dfrac{a-30}{2} & \text{if} & 30\le a\le 90\\[2px]
30+\dfrac{a-60}{4} & \text{if} & a>90
\end{cases}
$$

This *may* make sense but watch out: such $b(a)$ is continuous in $a=30$ but not in $a=90$. The last of three pieces may have been misunderstood, I think.

Comment: I should have formulated the question better. By example when $a$ is $45$, $b$ should be $(45-30)/2=7.5$. When $a$ is $120$, $b$ should be $30+(120-60)/4 =45$

Comment: @LennyWhite have a look now: I have a doubt about the third piece of $b(a)$...

Comment: @LennyWhite very possibly the third piece is $b(a)=30+\dfrac{a-90}{4}$ but this equals not $45$ when $a=120$.

Comment: Thank you, also you are right it should be 90 not 60. Is it possible to write this as a single formula instead of a piecewise function? Or use additional variables that are defined using piecewise function, and then express $b(a)$ with a single line?

Comment: @LennyWhite No: in the first piece $b(a)$ is a constant, in the other two it is not...

Comment: @LennyWhite piecewise function are piecewise for this reason :(